# SQL: Finding difference between latest two records grouped by user

Tags: sql, group-by

Suppose I had a Table with three columns:
[user_id, created_at, text]

Let U be the set of users that have at least two records.
How would I find the percentage of U for which there is no difference between the text in their latest two records?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       avg(case when min(text) = max(text) then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_same
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by user_id
having max(seqnum = 2)   -- make sure there are two records
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a notepad scribble (untested)

```
SELECT 100.0*SUM(samePrevText)/COUNT(*) as Perc
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, created_at, text,
     row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as rn,
     case when text = lead(text) over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) then 1 else 0 end as samePrevText
    FROM usertexts
) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but it seems to do the trick:

```sql
SELECT SUM((LatestTwoRowsEqual) * 1.00) / COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS UsersPercentage
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY user_id 
            ORDER BY created_at DESC
          ) <= 2 AND -- Only look at two latest rows per user_id
          MAX(text) OVER(
            PARTITION BY user_id 
            ORDER BY created_at DESC 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = text -- Check if values are the same
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END LatestTwoRowsEqual
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE user_id IN ( -- Only get users with at least two records
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
  )
) src
```

If you your DBMS supports the `LAG` function, you could use that too.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/39573/9)